# Why does "this" work differently when function is called with and without "new"

Tags: javascript

I Want Know Why If I Don't Call The Function Bike Before The Obj The Output Of Console.log of maker is Bajaj !

```js
function bike() {
  var name = "Ninja";
  this.maker = "Kawasaki";
  console.log(this.name + " " + maker);  // undefined Bajaj
}

var name = "Pulsar";
var maker = "Bajaj";
obj = new bike();
console.log(obj.maker);                  // "Kawasaki"
```

But if I Call It The Output of maker inside The Console.log is Kawasaki

```js
function bike() {
  var name = "Ninja";
  this.maker = "Kawasaki";
  console.log(this.name + " " + maker);  // undefined Kawasaki
}

var name = "Pulsar";
var maker = "Bajaj";
bike();
obj = new bike();
console.log(obj.maker);                  // "Kawasaki"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't call the function with `new`, `this` is the global `window` object, so `this.maker` is equivalent to `window.maker`. Global variables are properties of the `window` object, so `this.maker = 'Kawasaki` is reassigning the global variable `maker`.

For lots more information about `this`, see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?r=SearchResults&s=2|333.5049)

Comment: If the `'use strict'` directive is declared, then `this` is `undefined`.

Comment: That's true but irrelevant to the question, since it's not getting errors.

Comment: Perhaps, but other's may want to know "How To Deal With The This Keyword"

Comment: I'm not sure why you are being so combative. I only added some clarity as a comment. If my input bothers you, then flag it for a moderator.

Comment: I would go for my solution here. There are a lot of unanswered questions about the original provided example, but there are some reasonable expectations about what @Barmar was intending to accomplish in the first place. Also looks like too much unconstructive dialog in comments. That is frustrating. Glad you found a solution that works for you!

Comment: Thank Uu Guys I Understood !

Answer (score 0):

The context for `this` within a function defined in the global namespace is `window`.

You may want to create a class `Bike` and assign properties to it for later access.

```
let Bike = class {
  constructor(settings) {
    this.name = settings.name
    this.maker = settings.maker
    this.price = settings.price
  }
  get tax() { return 0.01 }
  changePrice(newPrice) {
    this.price = this.price + (this.tax * this.price)
    return this
  },
}
```

then...

```
let bike = new Bike({
  name: 'Some Name', 
  maker: 'Some Manufacturer',
  price: 1344, 
})
```

then later...

```
bike.changePrice(1500)
```

There are probably some more advanced concepts that you could apply when managing a data object like this, but that is the basics of how a class works.

Otherwise, you need to create functions that return an object where the properties are applied, then have functions on the object that can use `this` to refer to itself.

```
function Bike(settings) {
  return {
    name: settings.name,
    maker: settings.maker,
    price: settings.price,
    tax: 0.01,
    changePrice: function(newPrice) {
      this.price = this.price + (this.tax * this.price)
      return this
    },
  }
}
```

Same instantiation.

```
let bike = new Bike({
  name: 'Some Name', 
  maker: 'Some Manufacturer',
  price: 1344, 
})
```

Same API usage.

```
bike.changePrice(1500)
```